# How to move an element below elements with a class

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I have a list of items. Some number of items at the top have a class.

```
<ul>
    <li class="blue moveMeDown">1</li>
    <li class="blue">2</li>
    <li class="blue">3</li>
    <li class="blue">4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to write jQuery to move item 1 down below the items with the class `blue`. To target the last item with that class, I'm using this:

```
$elm.nextUntil(":not(.blue)").last()
```

That seems like a mess, and it doesn't even work if there is only 1 `blue` item. There must be a better way to do this.

[Here's the JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/Xb7ue/).

Current jQuery:

```
$("ul").on("click", ".moveMeDown", function(e){           
    var $elm = $(this);
        $elm
        .insertAfter($elm.nextUntil(":not(.blue)").last()) 
        .removeClass("blue");

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.moveMeDown', function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.insertAfter(self.parent().find('.blue').last()).removeClass('blue');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3yEep/).

Also, as T.J. Crowder pointed out, [in the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368234/how-to-move-an-element-below-elements-with-a-class#comment26970418_18368273), the following also works:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.moveMeDown', function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.insertAfter(self.siblings('.blue').last()).removeClass('blue');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3yEep/1/).

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: Yep, should do it. `self.parent().find('.blue')` could be `self.siblings('.blue')`, just to avoid interactions with descendant non-sibling elements.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("ul").on("click", ".moveMeDown", function(e){           
    var $elm = $(this);
    $(".blue:last").after($elm.removeClass("blue"));       
});
```

Or,

```
$("ul").on("click", ".moveMeDown", function(e){           
    var $lastBlue = $(this).parent().find(".blue").last(),
        $elm = $(this);

    $lastBlue.after($elm.removeClass("blue"));       
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xb7ue/7/

Comment: Not a good idea, for two reasons: 1. It will find the last `.blue` element **anywhere**, not just within the context of the same list. 2. Using jQuery's CSS extensions (`:last`) where avoidable prevents jQuery handing off to the browser's native `querySelectorAll`, which nearly all browsers have, impairing performance. It's actually better to use the `last` method, counter-intuitive as that may seem.